# PHP Use Array as Class's property

Tags: php

no matter where i search, i never found any rule that said class's property can't be an Array, but no matter how i tried, it never worked. It is against the rule to assign ARRAY as class's property? If so, is there any workaround? Here is my code

```
class Imperials{
protected $Data;

function __Construct($passedData){
       $this->$Data = $passedData;
       echo($this->$Data['Name']);
    }
}

$var = new Imperials(array('Name'='Buster','Race'='Nords'));
```

It would returned an error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property

Comment: first of all, you have mistake here `$var = new Imperials(array('Name'='Buster','Race'='Nords'));` shoud be `key` => `value`

Comment: You have a syntax error : `'Name'='Buster'` should be `'Name'=>'Buster'` same for `'Race'=>'Nords'`

Comment: Read about PHP [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: please, do read about PHP language syntax and grammar before posting here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `$this->Data` without the `$` instead of `$this->$Data` and use `=>` for the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
class Imperials{
    protected $Data;

    function __Construct($passedData){
        $this->Data = $passedData;
        echo($this->Data['Name']);
    }
}

$var = new Imperials(array('Name'=>'Buster','Race'=>'Nords'));
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, i there they are, the $ on property name!
as for the '=' instrad of '=>', it simply my mistake while reproduce the code here